# Hibernate and stored procedure relation and how to solve create temporary table problem which throws table exists exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have hibernate session and database session which temporary table relays on database session. But  I really wonder that if database connection pool does not close the database connection after transaction then how can we use temporary table when querying data from database.

I don't know if it is correct but as I know database session is related database connection.
Temp table is related to database session so each thread will have own's temp table.

What can be the strategy when using temporary tables with hibernate connection pool?

Comment: the pool sessions are shared, if really is a per session table, simply check if exists and drop or clear the table before use it (but if you do the `create table` in transaction never would exists after the final and required `drop table`)

Comment: After SQLEXCEPTION is thrown, I catch it in procedure and deleted temporary table. It fixed my issue